# aspnetboilerplate - CORS error for AbpUserConfiguration/GetAll

Tags: angular, cors, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine, aspnetboilerplate

I have hosted aspnetboilerplate asp.net core application as App service on azure and Angular application on Azure VM.

When Angular application tries to request asp.net core application, CORS error occures for AbpUserConfiguration/GetAll.

Surprisingly this works well when I run angular application from local workstation. This issue only occurs when I try to run angular application from Azure VM.

ConfigureServices function has correct sequence of CORS and MVC. Also tried with specific Origin and with AllowCredentials, but no luck.

```
        //Configure CORS for angular2 UI
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(DefaultCorsPolicyName, p =>
            {                    
                p.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });

        //MVC
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory(DefaultCorsPolicyName));
        });
```

Though we set AllowAnyOrigin and AllowAnyMethod the network request shows it as below

```
    Access-Control-Request-Headers:abp.tenantid,authorization,content-type
    Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
```

All responses are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Azure server webapp you must also enable CORS. I think you will need to add the address of the VM and not just the client site.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @andre-odendaal, I was missing that exact configuration. It working now.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest option for development purpose is to use chrome extension : 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Another option, ideally, is to allow access in your application's web.config file:

https://gist.github.com/Jalalhejazi/5653347

https://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html

Answer (score 0):

The code in your ConfigureServices is registering CORS functionality and creating a custom policy. You need to apply the policy in your application for use. If its intended to be a global policy, Apply the policy in Startup.cs Configure method, something like below

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // ...

    // global CORS policy
    app.UseCors(DefaultCorsPolicyName);

    // ...

    // IMPORTANT: Make sure UseCors() is called BEFORE this
    app.UseMvc()
}
```

Or, if it need to be applied to a specific controller, you can do the same by

```
[EnableCors(DefaultCorsPolicyName)]
public class SampleController : Controller 
{
  //Controller code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how we do it in AspnetBoilerplate;
You have to set CORS both in **ConfigureServices and Configure** methods.
ConfigureServices is used for dependency injection settings and Configure is used to specify how the ASP.NET application will respond to HTTP requests.

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //MVC
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory(DefaultCorsPolicyName));
    });

    //Configure CORS for angular2 UI
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(DefaultCorsPolicyName, builder =>
        {
            //App:CorsOrigins in appsettings.json can contain more than one address with splitted by comma.
            builder
                .WithOrigins(_appConfiguration["App:CorsOrigins"].Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(o => o.RemovePostFix("/")).ToArray())
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
    });

    //... other configurations ...

}
```

You have to set cors on Configure method as well.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    //Initializes ABP framework.
    app.UseAbp(options =>
    {
        options.UseAbpRequestLocalization = false; //used below: UseAbpRequestLocalization
    });

    app.UseCors(DefaultCorsPolicyName); //Enable CORS!

    AuthConfigurer.Configure(app, _appConfiguration);

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseAbpRequestLocalization();

    //... other configurations ...

}
```